# Match with Regex any number except a specific number

Tags: regex

Using regex I would like to match strings like:

- 3.2 Title 1
- 3.5 Title 2
- 3.10 Title 3

I did `@"^3\.\d+[ ]."`
But I would like to do not match strings of "3." followed by a single 1 like :

- 3.1 Title 4

I tried `@"^3\.[^1][ ]."` but it doesnt match strings like 3.10

So How can I match any numbers except the number 1?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)s:

```
@"^3\.(?!1\b)\d+ ."
```

**Explanation:**

```
^   # Start of the string
3\. # Match 3.
(?! # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 1  # the digit 1 
 \b # followed by a word boundary (i. e. assert that the number ends here)
)   # End of lookahead assertion
\d+ # Then match any number.
```